# How to set Border for table

Tags: javascript, css, border, external

I am trying to develop a web page using HTML and JavaScript languages.

And I have been also using external Javascript and External style sheets for development.

The problem is while using external style sheets in Javascript, I want to give some border for the table and its rows and cols.

Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

Comment: You have no access to this external file ?

Comment: are you trying to add this to the javascript file or stylesheet?

Comment: please include the code you are trying...

Answer (score 19):

HTML elements have property `style` that represents object with element's styles. If you modify it — you'll change style of your element.

```
elem.style.border = "1px solid #000"
// the same as
elem.style.borderWidth = "1px";
elem.style.borderColor = "#000";
elem.style.borderStyle = "solid";

// or

elem.style.borderTop = "4px dashed greed";
// the same as
elem.style.borderTopWidth = "4px";
elem.style.borderTopColor = "green";
elem.style.borderTopStyle = "dashed";
```

Using `borderTop`, `borderRight`, `borderBottom`, `borderLeft` properties you can change only borders what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this in your JavaScript:

```
object.style.border="1px solid red"; // 1px solid red can be anything you want...
```

W3schools can help you here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp

Just to confirm object in this example represents some this you have selected using `getElementById`, so...

```
var myTable = document.getElementById('tableID');

myTable.style.border="1px solid red";
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the jQuery Framework ? With jQuery you would be able to add the following code to achieve your goal:

```
$('table').css("border","1px solid #000");
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

In your CSS file code table: `td{border:1pix solid red}`.

Here `1pix=` gives your choice of border size, but it should be in the same format.  I think `solid=` is intensity of color. If you want to try something else, refer to [w3schools/table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp). `red=Color name` (you can give any desired color name).
If you want to give the color name in hexadecimal, just replace "red" with some hexadecimal value like `"#cdcdcd"` (it's not black).

If you still have doubt, just approach me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `Javascript` :-

```
elemt.style.borderBottom="1px solid red";
elemt.style.borderTop="1px solid green";
```

In `CSS` :-

```
.your-element{
  border-top:1px solid green;
  border-left:1px solid red; 
}
```

Works fine. The `CSS` style of writing and `Javascript` style of writing is bit different.